# React Firebase/Firestore arrayUnion() doesn't trigger snapshot listener

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have just run into this problem. I have an array of objects inside a document and when I update them using arrayUnion, the snapshot listener doesn't trigger.

However, it does trigger if I change for example a string value in the document.

Here is my code:
the snapshot listener:

```js
// snapshot listener for changes on user doc if user is !== null
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("user)");
        if (user) {
            const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(doc(db, "users", user.id), (doc) => {
                if (doc.exists()) {
                    console.log("updating user data");
                    const userData = { ...doc.data(), id: doc.id } as User;
                    console.log(userData);
                    setUser(userData);
                } else {
                    // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
                    console.log("couldn't update user data");
                }
            });
            return () => unsubscribe();
        }
    }, []);
```

the update function:

```js
const addToCart = () => {
        const cartProduct: CartProduct =
            selectedVariation === null
                ? {
                        product: product.firestoreId,
                        quantity,
                  }
                : {
                        product: product.firestoreId,
                        quantity,
                        selectedVariationId: selectedVariation,
                  };
        if (user) {
            updateDoc(doc(db, "users", user.id), {
                cart: arrayUnion(cartProduct),
            })
                .then(() => {
                    console.log("Document successfully updated!");
                    toast.success("Proizvod uspješno dodan u košaricu!");
                })
                .catch(() => {
                    toast.error("Došlo je do pogreške!");
                });
        } else {
            localStorage.setItem(
                "cart",
                JSON.stringify(
                    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart") || "[]").concat(
                        cartProduct
                    )
                )
            );
            console.log("Document successfully updated!");
            toast.success("Proizvod uspješno dodan u košaricu!");
        }
    };
```

the arrayUnion does make a change correctly in the database itself, but it doesn't trigger the snapshot listener

when I perform this:

```js
function handleSubmit(event: any) {
        event.preventDefault(); // sprijecava ponovno ucitavanje stranice

        setLoading(true);

        updateDoc(doc(db, "users", user?.id), {
            username: username,
        })
            .then(() => {
                toast.success("Uspješno ažurirani podaci");
                setEdit(false);
                setLoading(false);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error("Error updating document: ", error);
                setLoading(false);
            });
    }
```

it does trigger the snapshot listener

EDIT: providing screenshot of DB
[database-structure-for-user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lqOZ.png)

also found this https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/7133

EDIT 2: let me provide (a lot) more context

I have a firebase.ts file that looks like this:

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import {
    connectFirestoreEmulator,
    doc,
    getDoc,
    getFirestore,
    onSnapshot,
    setDoc,
} from "firebase/firestore";
import {
    getAuth,
    onAuthStateChanged,
    signInWithEmailAndPassword,
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
    signOut,
    connectAuthEmulator,
    reauthenticateWithCredential,
    EmailAuthProvider,
    updatePassword,
} from "firebase/auth";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const firebaseConfig = {
 //redacted
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const db = getFirestore(app);
export const auth = getAuth(app);
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
    console.log("development mode");
    const EMULATORS_STARTED: string = "EMULATORS_STARTED";
    const globalAny = global as any;
    if (!globalAny[EMULATORS_STARTED]) {
        globalAny[EMULATORS_STARTED] = true;
        connectFirestoreEmulator(db, "localhost", 8080);
        connectAuthEmulator(auth, "http://localhost:9099");
    }
}

const formatAuthUser = (user: any) => ({
    uid: user.uid,
    email: user.email,
});

export function useFirebaseAuth() {
    const [authUser, setAuthUser] = useState<AuthUser | null>(null);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [user, setUser] = useState<User | null>(null);

    const authStateChanged = async (authState: any) => {
        if (!authState) {
            setAuthUser(null);
            setUser(null);
            setLoading(false);
            return;
        }

        setLoading(true);
        var formattedUser: AuthUser = formatAuthUser(authState);
        setAuthUser(formattedUser);
        getDoc(doc(db, "users", formattedUser.uid)).then((doc) => {
            if (doc.exists()) {
                const userData = { ...doc.data(), id: doc.id } as User;
                setUser(userData);
            } else {
                // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
            }
        });
        setLoading(false);
    };

    const clear = () => {
        setAuthUser(null);
        setUser(null);
        setLoading(false);
    };

    const firebaseEmailPassSignIn = async (email: string, password: string) => {
        return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password).then(
            (userCredential) => {
                // Signed in
                return userCredential.user;
            }
        );
    };

    const firebaseCreateUserEmailPass = async (
        firstName: string,
        lastName: string,
        email: string,
        password: string,
        username: string
    ) => {
        createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password).then(
            async (userCredential) => {
                // Signed in
                var user = userCredential.user;
                try {
                    await setDoc(doc(db, "users", user.uid), {
                        firstName: firstName,
                        lastName: lastName,
                        email: email,
                        username: username,
                        role: "client",
                    });
                } catch (e) {
                    console.error("Error adding document: ", e);
                }
            }
        );
    };
    const router = useRouter();
    const firebaseSignOut = async () => {
        signOut(auth).then(clear);
        router.push("/");
    };

    const firebaseReauthenticate = async (password: string) => {
        const user = auth.currentUser;
        const credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(user.email, password);
        if (user) {
            return reauthenticateWithCredential(user, credential);
        }
    };

    const firebaseChangePassword = async (password: string) => {
        return updatePassword(auth.currentUser, password);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, authStateChanged);
        return () => unsubscribe();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (user) {
            console.log("user not null in firebaset.ts")
            const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(doc(db, "users", user.id), (doc) => {
                if (doc.exists()) {
                    console.log("updating user data");
                    const userData = { ...doc.data(), id: doc.id } as User;
                    console.log(userData);
                    setUser(userData);
                } else {
                    // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
                    console.log("couldn't update user data");
                }
            });
            return () => unsubscribe();
        }
    }, []);

    return {
        user,
        setUser,
        authUser,
        loading,
        firebaseEmailPassSignIn,
        firebaseCreateUserEmailPass,
        firebaseSignOut,
        firebaseReauthenticate,
        firebaseChangePassword,
    };
}
```

then I have the context.tsx which looks like this:

```js
import { createContext, useContext } from "react";
import { useFirebaseAuth } from "./firebase";

const AuthUserContext = createContext({
    user: null,
    setUser: (user: User) => {},
    authUser: null,
    loading: true,
    firebaseEmailPassSignIn: async (email: string, password: string) => {},
    firebaseCreateUserEmailPass: async (
        firstName: string,
        lastName: string,
        email: string,
        password: string,
        username: string
    ) => {},
    firebaseSignOut: async () => {},
    firebaseReauthenticate: async (password: string) => {},
    firebaseChangePassword: async (password: string) => {},
});

export function AuthUserProvider({ children }: any) {
    const auth: any = useFirebaseAuth();
    return (
        <AuthUserContext.Provider value={auth}>
            {children}
        </AuthUserContext.Provider>
    );
}

export const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthUserContext);
```

the whole app is wrapped with AuthUserProvider

I'm accessing the `user` state in each component I need it in via:

```js
const { user } = useAuth();
```

please let me know if I can provide anything else and I appreciate the help

I worked around the issue by not using arrayUnion and simply making a `newCart`, making all the changes needed there and updating the doc like this:

```js
updateDoc(doc(db, "users", user.id), {
                cart: newCart,
            })
```

however, **this stops triggering the listener as well** after a while

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem here, but my `onSnapshot` listener fires as expected: https://stackblitz.com/edit/firestore-v9-arrayunion

Comment: @AlexMamo I edited and provided the screenshot.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I found this: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/7133, it says this: "The bug happens only with complex object, not with simple strings." I understand that Date is also an object, but maybe not "complex" enough? I dont really know...

Comment: That's interesting, but not conclusive. Does the StackBlitz link I shared work when you try it? If so, can you fork and modify it to reproduce the problem?

Comment: yes, it works! however, my solution without arrayUnion seems to stop working after some time, so I'm completely at a loss right now what to do...

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I edited the original post, providing more context (hopefully not too much), and I also created a workaround that seemed to have worked, but stops working after a while...

Comment: I am not looking for a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link please, it's useful) of the problem. Hence my request for you to form the StackBlitz link I gave and reproducing the problem based on that.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I'm trying to reproduce it by following my code structure, but keeping it minimal, However, when I used the config from you stackblitz I'm getting errors for Missing or insufficient permissions when I try to create a user. I'm sorry if I'm being dumb, just really trying to figure this out, it's my first time posting here
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-byrdfe?file=pages%2Findex.jsx

Comment: You indeed won't have permission to write to my database, but you can use a database of your own and do the same.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I managed to figure out the issue and posted my solution. Thank you again for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the `if(user)` condition in the `firebase.ts` file for the snapshot listener:

```js
useEffect(() => {
        if (user) {
            console.log("user not null in firebaset.ts")
            const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(doc(db, "users", user.id), (doc) => {
                if (doc.exists()) {
                    console.log("updating user data");
                    const userData = { ...doc.data(), id: doc.id } as User;
                    console.log(userData);
                    setUser(userData);
                } else {
                    // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
                    console.log("couldn't update user data");
                }
            });
            return () => unsubscribe();
        }
    }, []);
```

If the user isn't initially logged in, the `user` will be `null` which would not initialize the listener. Since an empty dependency array was given, the `useEffect` hook won't rerun after login and the listener will never initialize.

The reason I thought it sometimes worked and sometimes didn't is because I would try to fix the hook causing a re-render and initializing the hook *manually* after I had been logged in and saw it not working.

I ultimately fixed it by replacing the condition with `if(authUser)` and adding the `authUser` to the dependency array causing the hook to re-run after the auth state changed, fetching the user doc via `authUser.uid` instead of `user.id`.

Thank you to everyone who commented and tried their best to help me!

Fixed `useEffect` hook:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (!authUser) {
      console.log("user listener not set");
      return;
    }
    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(
      doc(db, "users", authUser.uid),
      (doc) => {
        if (doc.exists()) {
          console.log("updating user data");
          const userData = { ...doc.data(), id: doc.id } as User;
          console.log(userData);
          setUser(userData);
        } else {
          // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
          console.log("couldn't update user data");
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log("error getting user data", error);
      }
    );
    console.log("user listener set");
    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, [authUser]);
```